# Implementing a simple search with Meteor and Iron Router

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, publish-subscribe, iron-router

In the next phase of my Meteor journey (read: learning the ropes!), I'd like to implement a simple search based on user inputed values, then redirect to a route specific to the record returned from the server.

At the moment, I'm picking up the inputed values via this code:

```
Template.home.events 'submit form': (event, template) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log 'form submitted!'
  countryFirst = event.target.firstCountrySearch.value
  countrySecond = event.target.secondCountrySearch.value
  Session.set 'countryPairSearchInputs', [countryFirst, countrySecond]
  countryPairSearchInputs = Session.get 'countryPairSearchInputs'
  console.log(countryPairSearchInputs)
  return Router.go('explore')
```

Happily, the console log returns the desired `countryPairSearchInputs` variable - an array of two ids. In my **routes.coffee** file I then have the following:

```
@route "explore",
    path: "/explore/:_id"
    waitOn: ->
      Meteor.subscribe 'countryPairsSearch'
```

On the server side, I have:

```
Meteor.publish 'countryPairsSearch', getCountryPairsSearch
```

And finally, I have a **search.coffee** file in my /lib directory that defines the `getCountryPairsSearch` function:

```
@getCountryPairsSearch = ->
  CountryPairs.findOne $and: [
    { country_a_id: $in: Session.get('countryPairSearchInputs') }
    { country_b_id: $in: Session.get('countryPairSearchInputs') }
  ]
```

With regards to the search function itself, I have a `CountryPairs` collection where each record has two ids (`country_a_id` and `country_b_id`) - the aim here is to allow users to input two countries, with the corresponding `CountryPair` then being returning.

I'm currently struggling to tie all the pieces together - the console output on searching is currently:

```
Uncaught Error: Missing required parameters on path "/explore/:_id". The missing params are: ["_id"]. The params object passed in was: undefined.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - as you can probably tell I'm new to Meteor and am still getting used to the pub/sub methodology!

Edited: mixed up client/server for the publish method when I first posted - the danger of late-night posting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, seems you're expecting an :id parameter on your 'explore' route.

If I understand you're case, you're not expecting any params here, so you can just delete ':id' from your route:

```
@route "explore",
path: "/explore/"
waitOn: ->
  Meteor.subscribe 'countryPairsSearch'
```

or either add a params to your Router.go call:

```
Router.go('explore', {_id: yourIdVar});
```

**Secondly**, you're trying to use a client function: Session.get() server-side. Try to update the publication using a parameter ; or using a method.call.

client-side

```
Meteor.subscribe 'countryPairsSearch' countryA countryB
```

not sure about the coffeescript syntax, check http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe

and server-side

```
@getCountryPairsSearch = (countryA, countryB) ->
  CountryPairs.findOne $and: [
    { country_a_id: $in: countryA }
    { country_b_id: $in: countryB }
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks - I actually made a typo RE: server/client in my original question, but the heads up on Session.get not being available server-side helped!